# Creating document set with workflow

Tags: workflow, document-library, document

I have 1 list and 1 Document library. In the "list" they create a list item which triggers on create. When the trigger happens it should create a document set folder in the "Document library" which should have the same title as the list element and content type Document set.

This dosent work, it still created it as a folder and not a document set.

I use a sharepoint 2013 Workflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create DocSet with Sharepoint 2013 workflow but you can create DocSet with Sharepoint 2010 workflow.

Kind Regards